# How to generate a HTML report for automated tests on Selenium with Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, pytest, report

I an using Selenium with Pytest to automate tests in the company I work for (as a Jr Automation QA) and I can generate a HTML report if I run the tests with the code "pytest --html=report.html" but I can only see the logs for the failed tests and I would like to, somehow, being able to implement logging for every step of every test in a way where they are readable in the report and a non-technical employee can understand what has been performed and what has failed. I uderstand this is possible with logging but for some reason I cannot make it work.

Could anyone explain how to achieve this?

Comment: You are likely talking about a monumental amount of work. Why does a non-technical person need that much detail? Why isn't what test pass/failed good enough for them? Ideally you have test case steps documented in some test case management software and the automated scripts linked to the corresponding test case so that if a test fails and the non-technical person wants to know what's being tested, they can look at the test case steps instead of the automation logs.

Comment: This is not as much related with what makes sense (which also changes from company to company and proyect to proyect) but more like something I would like to implement. Specially to learn and grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, Selenium does not come with a standard html reporter, so whatever reporting solution you are currently using is probably a third-party tool or plugin. In that case you will need to find out what html reporting tool you are using, and how the logging works for that tool.

As an example, one popular html reporting solution for selenium is Extent Report, which requires a log status parameter when logging (such as PASS, FAIL, SKIP, and INFO). More on Extent test here: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/extent-reports-in-selenium.

Finally, ensure that you're not trying to log your extra steps using generic log statements (such as console.log). Since you mentioned that failed test steps are already logged in your html report, you will want to find out which conditional statements or handlers are triggering those logs. Once you've located them, you should be able to find the syntax & expressions for logging elsewhere using your html reporter.

Hope that helps.